# Describe SELECT v.s. describe table in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, psql

`\d` does not seem to work except for a table in PostgreSQL.

I want to be able to retrieve the equivalent of `\d <table>`, but for a `SELECT` query.

For example, I would like to say:

```
\d (SELECT statement) AS table2
```

where the SELECT statement might contain JOINs and so on

just like in TimesTen:

```
desc  (SELECT .. FROM ... WHERE ...)
```

gives column info like name, type, and length

I can use `\pset footer on` or  `--expanded` but it doesn't give data type and length.

Comment: This is not possible in psql. Some GUI clients offer this though

Comment: GUI can fetch this from ODBC, but I need it in psql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mind doing it inside a transaction?

```
begin;
create table x as select * from t with no data;
\d x
                 Table "public.x"
 Column |            Type             | Modifiers 
--------+-----------------------------+-----------
 t      | timestamp without time zone | 

rollback;
```